# Only one TextView occurs in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-tablelayout

I need one in the left and the right. All configurations should be done by code. Screenshot:

[image]

Code:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.overview);
    loadData();
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tl);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    TableRow tr2 = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    //tr2.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    //tr2.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(L., LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    //tv.se
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    tv2.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    tv.setText("Test");
    tv2.setText("Test");
    //tv.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    //tv.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    tv2.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    //tv.setTextSize(50);
    //tv2.setTextSize(50);
    tr.addView(tv);
    tr.addView(tv2);
    //tl.addView(tr);
    //setContentView(tl);
    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
```

Layout:

```
<TableLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/tl"
  android:stretchColumns="*">
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Why you are not using xml layout for all `TextView` elements and only for `TableLayout`?

Comment: Do you need to use a table layout? It seems like a relative layout would suit your needs better.

Comment: @user5779 I think tv2 is ovelapping tv try changing text of any one tv see that.....

Comment: only the first  TextView appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use:

```
  android:stretchColumns="0,1"
```

Great Example can be found [here](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/07/01/android-creating-tablerow-rows-inside-a-tablelayout-programatically/)

do this:

> remove 1f from tv2 layoutparams.
>
> tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
>                       LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
>                       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

this may solve you problem according to given link.

Answer (score 2):

LayoutParams are used by views to tell their parents how they want to be laid out.
There are around 13 different types of LayoutParams defined in Android. eg. LinearLayout.Layoutparams, ViewGroup.LayoutParams, ActionBar.LayoutParams etc.

So if one is adding TextView to LinearLayout, it means LinearLayout is the parent of TextView, so while defining layout parameteres for textView one should use 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams and not ViewGroup.LayoutParams

in your case you are adding two textviews to table row, so but obvious you should use TableRow.LayoutParams

so replace this line

```
tv2.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```

with

```
tv2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```

Write similarly for tv
**This was my first post on this site. Hope it will be Helpful :)**